# Is there an Authorize.net API endpoint for getting a list of shipping addresses for a single customer profile?

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I am working on part of an application that will let customers add/edit/delete their saved shipping addresses using the Authorize.net API. At this point I can do everything I need to do except get a list of all the saved shipping addresses for a single customer.

Eventually, I want to display a list of existing shipping addresses associated with a logged in customer.

Is there a way to get a list of shipping address information? And, are shipping addresses secretly the same as billing addresses?

I've looked through the API Documentation and [developer guide on customer profiles](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/customer-profiles.html#Customers), but I can't find an answer.

I know I can get a single address for a customer if I know the customerAddressId.

I know I can use the getCustomerProfile endpoint to get a list of payment profiles for a given customerProfileId. Each payment profile contains a billTo address, but not a shipping address.

Comment: I found the place in the API response where this information gets returned. It is called shipToList in the response to getCustomerProfileRequest. 

shipToList : One or more of this field will be returned for any shipping profiles associated with this customer.

Now I need to find a way to include this information in my sandbox responses.

Comment: Answered! The shipToList comes back as part of the JSON response payload in getCustomerProfile. I wasn't seeing the field because there wasn't any data at the point I tested that API call.

After I had added shipping addresses to my test customer and called getCustomerProfile again, I was able to see the shipTo list in the response body.